# Javascript creating a li element and assigning text to data-attribute is being truncated

Tags: javascript, html

In javascript I am creating a li element as per below which contains only the problem I am seeing.

The data-videoUrl is showing the full url, so all good there.

The issue is the entry.link and entry.title, while debugging, I verified the strings are within quotes. i.e. "This is a pod cast." The data-videoTitle and data-videoDesciption are being truncated though. i.e. "This" will show from the previous example.

I'm not sure what is occuring in the latter two data assignments as I've verified the text is not double quoted etc.  What is occuring with the html5 data elements? I can provide a more complete example if needed.

```
      var podItem = document.createElement("li");
      podItem.innerHTML = entry.title
      + "<a data-videoUrl=" + entry.link + " "
      + "data-videoTitle=" + entry.title + " "
      + "data-videoDescription=" + entry.contentSnippet + " "
      + "</a>";
      document.getElementById("podCastList").innerHTML += podItem.innerHTML;
```

Here is a the html being generated.

```
 <a data-videourl="http://rss.cnn.com/~r/services/podcasting/studentnews/rss/~3/d3y4Nh_yiZQ/orig-sn-060614.cnn.m4v" data-videotitle="CNN" student="" news="" -="" june="" 6,="" 2014="" data-videodescription="For" our="" last="" show="" of="" the="" 2013-2014="" school="" year,="" cnn="" takes="" a="" look="" back,="" ahead,="" and="" at="" stories="" making="" ...="" <=""></a>
```

I'm sure there's something I'm not fully understanding. Why would the first data element get the text correctly, and the next two data elements break up the text as in: [data-videotitle="CNN" student="" news=""]. The text is a straight forward sentence quoted i.e. "CNN student news..."

Why would videoUrl work correctly and the other two not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add some quotes around the attributes...

```
  podItem.innerHTML = entry.title
  + "<a data-videoUrl=\"" + entry.link + "\" "
  + "data-videoTitle=\"" + entry.title + "\" "
  + "data-videoDescription=\"" + entry.contentSnippet + "\" "
  + "</a>";
```

You'll also want to make sure you escape any quotes that are inside the attributes as well.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the attributes Anthony. Successful.